# How to copy selected file to app's directory

Tags: ios, swift, url, file-manager

I'm new to `FileManager` in iOS.
I'm trying to create a simple app: there's a list of files, and when the user press a cell the the file opens. The user can also add new files.

This is what I currently have:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

var urls: [URL] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

@IBAction func newButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let types = UTType(tag: "pdf", tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: nil)!
    let controller = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [types])
    controller.delegate = self
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    for url in urls {
        self.storeAndShare(withURL: url)
    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return urls.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

    cell.textLabel?.text = urls[indexPath.row].localizedName

    return cell
}

lazy var documentInteractionController: UIDocumentInteractionController = {
    let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController()
    vc.delegate = self
    return vc
}()

func share(url: URL) {
    documentInteractionController.url = url
    documentInteractionController.uti = url.typeIdentifier ?? "public.data, public.content"
    documentInteractionController.name = url.localizedName ?? url.lastPathComponent
    documentInteractionController.presentPreview(animated: true)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    share(url: self.urls[indexPath.row])
}

func storeAndShare(withURL url: URL) {
    /// START YOUR ACTIVITY INDICATOR HERE
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        let direcotryURL = URL(string: FileManager.default.currentDirectoryPath)!
        let newURL = direcotryURL.appendingPathComponent(response?.suggestedFilename ?? "fileName.pdf")
        
        do {
            try data.write(to: newURL)
        } catch let err {
            print("ERROR: \(err).")

            // Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=/doc.pdf}

            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            /// STOP YOUR ACTIVITY INDICATOR HERE
            self.urls.append(newURL)
            self.share(url: newURL)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        }.resume()
}

}

extension TableViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
/// If presenting atop a navigation stack, provide the navigation controller in order to animate in a manner consistent with the rest of the platform
func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller:  UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
    guard let navVC = self.navigationController else {
        return self
    }
    return navVC
}
}
extension URL {
var typeIdentifier: String? {
    return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.typeIdentifierKey]))?.typeIdentifier
}
var localizedName: String? {
    return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.localizedNameKey]))?.localizedName
}
}
```

I have problems with the `storeAndShare()` function. I'm trying to copy the selected file to the app's directory, and then add the new URL to the urls list (`self.urls`).
But it doesn't work, and gives me an error in data.write:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file couldn’t be saved because the specified URL type isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=/doc.pdf}

Why is this happening? and how can I achieve what I need? thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `URLSession`?  Have you found out it's for?

Comment: No, as I said I'm really new to this. Most of my code is copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant mistake is `currentDirectoryPath`. You must not use it to get the path to the Documents directory. You have to call `url(for:in:appropriateFor:create:` or `urls(for:in:)` of `FileManager`

And – if we are talking about local files – `URLSession` is the wrong way, too.

```
func storeAndShare(with url: URL) {

    let directoryURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let newURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
    
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: newURL)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.urls.append(newURL)
            self.share(url: newURL)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error).")
    }
}
```

Comment: Placed it instead of my current function and it gives me an error in second line: Cannot find 'response' in scope

Answer (score 1):

"/doc.pdf"

Is not writable for you.

Get the documents directory:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
```

And save your file there (instead of using `currentDirectoryPath`).